# Блог на JSF/CDI. Как организовать хранение статей?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsf

Коллеги, подскажите:

1. Как на JSF можно организовать хранение статей, чтобы не создавать под каждую из них отдельную xhtml страницу и у каждой был свой URL?
2. Также интересует вопрос, как на JSF при навигации не перерисовывать всю страницу, а только ее контентную часть(возможно это одинаковым способом решается)?

Comment: Технология _JSF_ позволяет создавать страницы с динамическим содержимым с помощью _Expression Language_. Это, собственно, и означает, что Вам не нужно создавать страницу под каждую статью. В _JSF_ есть встроенная поддержка _AJAX_, с помощью ее можно перерисовывать часть страницы.

Comment: Да, это более менее понятно. Но как к этому добывать определенный URL? Может быть в JSF есть некоторое событие, которое генерируется при изменении адреса, чтобы потом с помощью <f:ajax> перерисовать часть страницы?

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, надо было в сторону фильтров смотреть.